# Grunt build and serve relative path mismatch

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, webstorm, git-submodules

I have my angular app set up with a typical directory structure. I also have a git submodule in the app directory:

```
app
  submod
    submod.js
    submod.css
bower_components
dist
node_modules
bower.json
Gruntfile.js
package.json
...
```

My index.html is set up for the `grunt build` task. Everything works fine except for the submodule files, because the path causes problems.

If I put 'app' in the path, the build will work correctly:

```
<!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
  <!-- bower:css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <!-- ... -->
  <!-- endbower -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/submod/submod.css" />
<!-- endbuild -->
```

However, running the app locally with `grunt serve` will not work unless I remove app from the path:

```
<!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
  <!-- bower:css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <!-- ... -->
  <!-- endbower -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="submod/submod.css" />
<!-- endbuild -->
```

But then the build task won't work, because it can't find the files!

So I have a mismatch in the paths, because `grunt serve` seems to start looking for relative paths from within the app directory, whereas `grunt build` starts looking from the root. I can change the path manually when I want to build or serve, but it gets quite tedious, and it would be nice to have this automated.

Here is my Gruntfile.js. It is in the root directory.

```
// Generated on 2014-07-08 using generator-angular 0.9.2
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

// Load grunt tasks automatically
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

// Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
require('time-grunt')(grunt);

// Configurable paths for the application
var appConfig = {
    app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
};

// Define the configuration for all the tasks
grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    yeoman: appConfig,

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
        bower: {
            files: ['bower.json'],
            tasks: ['wiredep']
        },
        js: {
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
            tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
            options: {
                livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
            }
        },
        jsTest: {
            files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
            tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
        },
        styles: {
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css', '<%= yeoman.app %>/less/{,*/}*.less'],
            tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer', 'less']
        },
        gruntfile: {
            files: ['Gruntfile.js']
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
            },
            files: [
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
                '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
            ]
        }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
        options: {
            port: 9000,
            // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
            hostname: 'localhost',
            livereload: 35729
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                open: true,
                middleware: function (connect) {
                    return [
                        connect.static('.tmp'),
                        connect().use(
                            '/bower_components',
                            connect.static('./bower_components')
                        ),
                        connect.static(appConfig.app)
                    ];
                }
            }
        },
        test: {
            options: {
                port: 9001,
                middleware: function (connect) {
                    return [
                        connect.static('.tmp'),
                        connect.static('test'),
                        connect().use(
                            '/bower_components',
                            connect.static('./bower_components')
                        ),
                        connect.static(appConfig.app)
                    ];
                }
            }
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                open: true,
                base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            }
        }
    },

    //update dev dependencies
    devUpdate: {
        main: {
            options: {
                updateType: 'report', //just report outdated packages
                reportUpdated: false, //don't report up-to-date packages
                semver: true, //stay within semver when updating
                packages: {
                    devDependencies: true, //only check for devDependencies
                    dependencies: true
                },
                packageJson: null, //use matchdep default findup to locate package.json
                reportOnlyPkgs: [] //use updateType action on all packages
            }
        }
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
            reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
        },
        all: {
            src: [
                'Gruntfile.js',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
            ]
        },
        test: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
            },
            src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
        }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                dot: true,
                src: [
                    '.tmp',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*',
                    '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
                ]
            }]
        },
        server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    autoprefixer: {
        options: {
            browsers: ['last 1 version']
        },
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/'
            }]
        }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    wiredep: {
        app: {
            src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
            ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
        }
    },

    //compile less
    less: {
        development: {
            options: {
                compess: true,
                yuicompress: true,
                optimization: 2,
                paths: 'bower_components/bootstrap/less'
            },
            files: {
                // target.css file: source.less file
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/custom.css': '<%= yeoman.app %>/less/custom.less'
            }
        }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    filerev: {
        dist: {
            src: [
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'//,
                //'<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
            ]
        }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
        html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
        options: {
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
            flow: {
                html: {
                    steps: {
                        js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
                        css: ['cssmin']
                    },
                    post: {}
                }
            }
        }
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
        css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
        options: {
            assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>','<%= yeoman.dist %>/images']
        }
    },

    // The following *-min tasks will produce minified files in the dist folder
    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
    // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
    // to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //   //dist: {
    //   //  files: {
 //   //   '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
 //   //     '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
 //   //   ],
 //   // }
    //   //},
 //  options: {
 //    sourceMap: 'true'
 //  }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //   dist: {}
    // },

    imagemin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
            }]
        }
    },

    svgmin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
            }]
        }
    },

    htmlmin: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                conservativeCollapse: true,
                collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                removeOptionalTags: true
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                src: ['*.html', 'views/{,*/}*.html'],
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            }]
        }
    },

    // ng-annotate adds and removes AngularJS dependency injection annotations.
    // It is non-intrusive so your source code stays exactly the same otherwise.
    // No lost comments or moved lines
    ngAnnotate: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
                src: '*.js',
                dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
            }]
        }
    },

    // Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
        dist: {
            html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
        }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                src: [
                    '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                    '.htaccess',
                    '*.html',
        '*.svg',
                    'views/{,*/}*.html',
                    'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
                    'styles/images/browsers/*',
                    'fonts/*'
                ]
            }, {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '.',
                flatten: true,
                src: 'bower_components/fontawesome/fonts/*',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/fonts'
            },
                {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/images',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
                    src: ['generated/*']
                }, {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist',
                    src: 'fonts/*',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
      }, {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/angular-geneview-vis/src',
        src: 'geneview-template.html',
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/angular-geneview-vis/src'
      }
      //, {
      //  expand: true,
      //  cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
      //  src: '*',
      //  dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/.tmp/concat/scripts'
      //}
      //, {
      //  expand: true,
      //  cwd: 'app/angular-chromosome-vis',
      //  src: ['*.js', '*.css'],
      //  dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/angular-chromosome-vis'
      //}, {
      //  expand: true,
      //  cwd: 'app/angular-geneview-vis/src',
      //  src: ['*.js', '*.css', '*.html'],
      //  dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/angular-geneview-vis/src'
      //}
      ]
        },
        styles: {
            expand: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
            dest: '.tmp/styles/',
            src: '{,*/}*.css'
        }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
    concurrent: {
        server: [
            'copy:styles'
        ],
        test: [
            'copy:styles'
        ],
        dist: [
            'copy:styles',
            'imagemin',
            'svgmin'
        ]
    },

    // Test settings
    karma: {
        unit: {
            configFile: 'test/karma.conf.js',
            singleRun: true
        }
    }
});


grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
        return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'wiredep',
        'concurrent:server',
        'autoprefixer',
        'connect:livereload',
        'watch'
    ]);
});

grunt.registerTask('server', 'DEPRECATED TASK. Use the "serve" task instead', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
});

grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test',
    'karma'
]);

grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
]);

grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
]);
};
```

Comment: Can you please post your Gruntfile.js?

Comment: Hi, your grunt serve watch in your app directory ?

Comment: @sobolevn I just added it.

Comment: @OlivierRodomond If I understand your question, the Gruntfile is in the root directory, not in the app directory.